# gramian matrix and trace relationship

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, intuition, trace

Suppose $M$ is an $n \times m$ incidence matrix of a simple graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. 
As an exercise in my graph theory course, we proved the diagonals of $M^T M$ equal $2$ for any simple graph.

While determining whether I actually believed this or not using NumPy, I stumbled upon a larger idea that exposed a lack of my understanding in Linear Algebra.

For any $n \times m$ matrix $A$ I speculate that, 
$$tr(A^TA) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{m}a_{ij}^2$$

Which now makes me think of trace as a function describing the "size" of a matrix i.e. when performing a matrix vector product how small or large can we expect differences to be in our resultant vector from different perturbations of input vectors?

> Is my assumption wrong? If not, is there any intuition on why this is true?

I'm not satisfied with the thought that "the math just works out".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's consider $A$ to be a real matrix.

Let the $j$-th column of $A$ be $A_j$.

$(i,j)$-th entry of $A^TA$ computes the $A_i^TA_j$. That is the $(i,j)$-th element of $A^TA$ measures the dot product between $A_i$ and $A_j$.

Hence, $(j,j)$-th entry of $A^TA$ computes $A_j^TA_j =\|A_j\|^2 =\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}^2$. That is the $(j,j)$-th element of $A^TA$ measure $\|A_j\|^2$.

Trace sums up the diagonals elements, hence

$$\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)=\sum_{j=1}^m \|A_j\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^na_{ij}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ma_{ij}^2$$

Remark:
For real matrices,

$$\|A\|_F = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)}$$ is known as the Frobenius norm.

For complex matrices, $$\|A\|_F = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(A^\dagger A)}$$